# gulp test: fileExists is not a function

Tags: typescript, gulp

Our tests recently started failing when tslint updated and changed its' dependency to typescript v2. Once we updated the necessary version #s in our package json, these errors started appearing once gulp test was executed.

Module build failed: TypeError: fileExists is not a function at Object.findConfigFile (/Users/###/contacts-ui/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:58911:17)

I set all the gulp modules to ^ instead of ~ version #s thinking it was another dependency issue, but nothing seems to be working. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Here's a copy of our npm package json file...

```
{
"name": "pccrm",
"version": "0.0.0",
"scripts": {
"test": "gulp test"
},
"devDependencies": {
"angular-feature-toggle": "^0.1.6",
"awesome-typescript-loader": "~0.14.0",
"bower": "^1.6.5",
"browser-sync": "~2.9.11",
"browser-sync-spa": "~1.0.3",
"chalk": "~1.1.1",
"del": "~2.0.2",
"eslint-plugin-angular": "~0.12.0",
"estraverse": "~4.1.0",
"gulp": "^3.9.0",
"gulp-angular-templatecache": "^1.8.0",
"gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.0.2",
"gulp-eslint": "^1.0.0",
"gulp-filter": "^3.0.1",
"gulp-flatten": "^0.2.0",
"gulp-if": "^2.0.0",
"gulp-inject": "^3.0.0",
"gulp-less": "^3.0.3",
"gulp-load-plugins": "^0.10.0",
"gulp-minify-css": "^1.2.1",
"gulp-minify-html": "^1.0.5",
"gulp-notify": "^2.2.0",
"gulp-print": "^2.0.1",
"gulp-protractor": "^1.0.0",
"gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
"gulp-replace": "^0.5.4",
"gulp-rev": "^6.0.1",
"gulp-rev-replace": "^0.4.2",
"gulp-size": "^2.0.0",
"gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
"gulp-tslint": "^6.0.0",
"gulp-typescript": "^3.0.0",
"gulp-uglify": "^1.4.1",
"gulp-useref": "^1.3.0",
"gulp-util": "^3.0.6",
"http-proxy-middleware": "~0.9.0",
"karma": "~0.13.10",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.2",
"karma-coverage": "^0.5.5",
"karma-firefox-launcher": "^0.1.7",
"karma-htmlfile-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"karma-jasmine": "^0.3.7",
"karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "^0.2.1",
"karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^0.2.3",
"less": "^2.6.1",
"lodash": "~3.10.1",
"main-bower-files": "~2.9.0",
"ng-annotate-loader": "0.0.10",
"phantomjs": "~2.1.1",
"protractor": "^2.5.1",
"run-sequence": "^1.1.5",
"sinon": "^1.17.2",
"tsd": "^0.6.5",
"tslint": "^4.0.0",
"tslint-loader": "^1.0.2",
"typescript": "^2.0.0",
"uglify-save-license": "~0.4.1",
"webpack-stream": "~2.1.1",
"wiredep": "~2.2.2",
"wrench": "~1.5.8"
},
"engines": {
"node": ">=0.10.0"
},
"dependencies": {
"del": "^2.0.2",
"feature-toggle": "^0.2.0",
"gulp-debug": "^2.1.2",
"gulp-git": "^1.6.0"
}
}
```